# Invalid .resx file after renamed namespace

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, namespaces, resx

Consider the following situation:

- In my Windows Forms appliation I have a form.
- That form has a .resx file.
- The form makes use of a class ("OtherClass") from another assembly ("Other.dll").
- "Other.dll" is built in the same VisualStudio 2010 solution as the main application
  (just a separate project in the same solution).
- In the main project (the Windows Forms application) I have properly
  added a reference to the "Other.dll" project.

Everything works well (as expected).

Now I need to change the namespace of the type contained in "Other.dll" from "Old.Namespace" to "New.Namespace":

1. In VS2010, I bring up the Properties window of the "Other.dll"
   project
2. I change the namespace in the "Default namespace" text box from "Old.Namespace" to
   "New.Namespace"
3. I change namespaces in related .cs files accordingly
4. I rebuild the modified "Other.dll" project. No errors. The modified "Other.dll" is produced OK.

Now comes the problem:

When I after this rebuild the whole solution, the compiler stops and reports that the .resx file of the form is invalid:

---

**"Invalid Resx file. Could not load type *Old.Namespace.OtherType*, Other, Version 1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null which is used in the .RESX file. Ensure that the necessary references have been added to your project. Line 1521, position 5"**

---

Clearly, the .resx file still references the type with the *old* namespace from somewhere. That "somewhere" appers to be from inside the binary section of the .resx file!

**Question:**
How can I make the .resx understand that it must now reference the new type (with the changed namespace)?

Please help, I really don't know how to proceed here...

Comment: Have you tried the "run custom tool option"(right click) on your resx?

Comment: Did you try to remove the reference to Other.dll and re-add that? Maybe the "copy local=True" may cause the problem..

Comment: No. But when I right click the .resx file in Solution Explorer I don't see any "run custom tool" in the pop-up menu??? Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Sorry my comment crossed another one. Yes, I tried to remove the reference and add it back. Same problem.

Answer (score 10):

I've had the same problem and the solution was to remove the data sections from the resx file

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same problem, and after trying several other options I followed Stefania Mereut's [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16662481/1084592) and deleted the data sections from the resx file.  When I re-added the resources, it apparently rewrote the data sections correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I was updating a reference to a new version of a dll. In my case, the references had the option "specific version" = true. In that case, it is not possible to deserialize an old version of a class inside the res file because it contains the version of the old class on it.
I changed the option on my refereces "specific version" from "true" to "false" and everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the resx file manually and change the type name of this binary resource to the new correct type name.  I'm guessing this is a non-standard (i.e. not a string or image) resource that's been added manually to the resx file directly.

I believe these can only be viewed in the 'Other' section of the ResX editor - they can't be added through it.